# How is data stored prior to downloading?

Tags: database, data, json, xml, csv

I go to several sites that offer their data in XML, JSON, CSV formats.  As shown here,
https://www.space.org/basicspacedata/query/class/boxscore/format/csv, I choose the format.  Question is how is the data stored on whatever database they use?  Certainly they don't store the same data in different formats?  Are the formats 'wrapped' when downloading, and 'stripped' while uploading?

Comment: The only person who can tell you that is the person who wrote the backend code for that website. You will have to ask them, not us.

Comment: Why would they not pre-generate and store the alternative formats? Disk space is dirt cheap, certainly cheaper than the added cost in salary and complexity that encoding-on-the-fly would add to the project.

Answer (score 0):

> How is data stored prior to downloading?

It probably is *not* stored but generated on the fly. Today, the bottleneck could be the network, not the processor or the disk.

For example, you could use [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) with [sqlite](https://sqlite.org) and [jansson](https://digip.org/jansson/) to code such a JSON + database [web service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service). Or [Apache Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) for XML.

Read [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report and look into the source code of [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) for an example.

Read much more about [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) and [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) (e.g. [PostGreSQL](https://postgresq.org/) database server) and [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI)

See also the Web and database related extensions or functions in [Go](https://go-lang.org/), [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), [Ocsigen](https://ocsigen.org/home/intro.html), [Haxe](https://haxe.org/), [POCO C++ library](https://pocoproject.org/), [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/guile.html), [Python](https://python.org/), [PHP](https://www.php.net/) ....